# Is it possible to add custom build tool to IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm currently working on some projects using the [Eta](http://eta-lang.org/) programming language.

It is a new purely functional programming language that runs on the JVM. Because of this, sometimes it requires to write Java code to make wrappers.

Currently, I'm working using Emacs, but for Java, I think that IntelliJ is the best IDE out there.

The thing is, Eta relies on a custom build tool, called Etlas. And although there are plugins for SBT and Gradle, Etlas works the best for Eta.

Etlas handles maven dependencies itself. Is there a way of adding this build tool to IntelliJ so it can see where the dependencies were downloaded and one can use the Java autocompletion when working on Java code?